# Initializing QGenericMatrix

Tags: c++, qt, matrix-multiplication

I need a matrix for matrix multiplication for neural networks and since I use the Qt Framework which provides QGenericMatrix I thought I give it a try. But I have no idea how to initialize the matrix with data.

It got this constructor but I am not able to use it right.

```
QGenericMatrix::QGenericMatrix(const T * values)
```

So it would help if someone could give me an example initialization for e.g.

```
    QGenericMatrix<2,2,int> a();
```

If I search for QGenericMatrix I hardly find anything except the [official class definition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html), so I was wondering if QGenericMatrix is a good choice at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is simple to pass values directly to the constructor:

```
int values[] = {
    1, 2,
    3, 4
};

QGenericMatrix<2,2,int> matrix(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or declare a array literal as a constructor parameter.

```
QGenericMatrix<2, 2, int> a( new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
```

Comment: According to Valgrind's Memcheck this leaks memory and thus should not be used.

Comment: Doesn't even compile, with g++ 9.2.1 using `-std=c++11`. "expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token" followed by "too many initializers for ‘int [1]’". Specifying the array size (`a ( new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4} );`) does compile, but valgrind still complains that 16 bytes are "definitely lost".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a generic solution that is comfortable to use, consider this template:

```
/** @internal
 *
 * @brief Convenience constructor for QGenericMatrix.
 *
 * @tparam N columns
 * @tparam M rows
 * @tparam T typename
 * @param args Initialization values. The number of arguments must be
 * exactly N × M.
 *
 * @returns The corresponding QGenericMatrix. */
template<int N, int M, typename T, typename... Args>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr QGenericMatrix<N, M, T> createMatrix(Args... args)
{
    // Too few arguments leave values uninitialized, too many arguments
    // result in compiler warnings.
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N * M, "Invalid number of arguments.");
    const T valueArray[] = {args...};
    return QGenericMatrix<N, M, T>(valueArray);
}
```

It’s easy to use:

```
auto temp = createMatrix<2, 2, int>(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Also, it’s safe, because it guarantees that all matrix fields are actually initialized (something that could go wrong when the array has less fields than the matrix).